# My app is showing as not compatible with any of my devices in a browser but is fine in the playstore app

Tags: android

I hope this question is considered on topic.

I am selling an app (**3DCARP**) on playstore and everything has been going well.

Recently I made an update (I have changed nothing in the manifest other than the version number).

> Now when I use a browser such as Chrome on my PC to view it in
>   playstore it is listed as not compatible with any of my devices.

If I do the same on the actual devices using the playstore app it shows up fine and will allow a purchase.

This seems very odd! Does anyone know why it show as incompatible when viewed in a browser?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem in my application.

Comment: Is it a recent problem for you?

Comment: I added one beta version to Play store in the last month. Then I update the same in the last week. So all users get the update notification and while update time, they face the same issue. So a lot of customers report the same issue.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same account on both PC and Mobile Device?

Comment: I have emailed google about this 3 times now - and no reply from them!